# Why do we need a preloader and a bootloader in many applications before even the main program

Tags: fpga, bootloader, psoc

I have read the datasheet of Altera's new HPS. It shows a chart where it shows:
Boot ROM -> Preloader -> Bootloader -> OS

I am wondering, why do we need a "pre-loader" and than the "bootloader" and than the OS? I have already read questions concerning bootloaders on this great forum and have some idea of what it is supposed to do. I understand that there are different type of bootloaders and their purpose is not the same in every case.

What I am confused about is this thing that we describe as preloader, why is it there?

Comment: Presumably the process described in this PDF: http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/hb/arria-v/av_5400A.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Diagram of Loading Process**

[image: Loading Process]

It doesn't sound like you read very far into the datasheet.  From page *A-4*:

**Preloader**

*The function of the preloader is user-defined. However, typical functions include 
initializing the SDRAM interface and configuring the HPS I/O pins. Initializing the 
SDRAM allows the preloader to load the next stage of the boot software (that might 
not fit in the 60 kilobytes (KB) available in the on-chip RAM). A typical next software 
stage is the open source boot loader, U-boot. The preloader is allowed to load the next stage boot software from any device 
available to the HPS. Typical sources include the same flash device that contains the 
preloader, a different flash device, or a communication interface such as an EMAC.*

This is from the datasheet [pcj50 linked.](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/hb/arria-v/av_5400A.pdf)